# Add additional column to the query output

Tags: mysql, sql, date, count, sum

I have the following query that is grabbing data from a table and combining all the products into one column and counting the quantity of that order.

I need to add an additional column to the output though, how can I also add `ship_date`?

```
select order_id, group_concat(product_id, ' - ', cnt separator ', ') as products, sum(cnt) as total
from (select order_id, product_id, count(*) as cnt
      from tt_order_items
      group by order_id, product_id
     ) op
group by order_id;
```

This is how the original table is laid out:

[image: l]

And this is how the query outputs the results:

[image]

How can I add `ship_date` to that output?

Comment: Please show the results that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *looks like* `ship_date` is fixed for each and every `order_id`. If so, you can just add it to the inner and outer aggregation:

```
select 
    order_id, 
    group_concat(product_id, ' - ', cnt separator ', ') as products, 
    sum(cnt) as total,
    ship_date
from (
    select order_id, product_id, count(*) as cnt, ship_date
    from tt_order_items
    group by order_id, product_id, ship_date
) op
group by order_id, ship_date;
```